# Is there a name for this construction? (taking a pairing and obtaining a perfect one)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, terminology

I believe that if we are given two modules $M,N$ over a ring $R$, and a pairing between them
$M \otimes_R N \to R$, we can construct a perfect pairing $M'\otimes_R N' \to R$ by taking kernels.

Is there a name for this construction?

Thanks.

Comment: associated perfect/non-degenerate pairing?

Comment: In general, won't it be only a nondegenerate pairing, instead of a perfect one?